# how to use event onChange in ionic2

Tags: angular, ionic2

Basically I am trying to make a registration form in which I have some drop down lists. And I want to apply "(change)" event on it which will trigger a function whenever value will be changed or we can say value be selected from that drop down list and based on that I will be assigning next fields dynamically but this event is not working on drop-down while its working fine with text fields.
Can someone help me out with this?

Sample code:

home.html -->

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content padding>

<form [formGroup]="myForm">   
    <ion-item>
        <ion-label>Dropdown1 :</ion-label>
        <ion-select formControlName="dd" (ionChange)='f()'  #dd>
         <ion-option value='1'>A</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='2'>B</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='3'>C</ion-option>
            <ion-option value='4'>D</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

     <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Dropdown2 :</ion-label>
    <ion-select>
     <ion-option value='1'>E</ion-option>
        <ion-option value='2'>F</ion-option>
        <ion-option value='3'>G</ion-option>
        <ion-option value='4'>H</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
</ion-item>

</form> 
</ion-content>
```

home.ts -->

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {

  }

  function f(){
  alert('Value Changed!');
  alert(this.myForm.dd);

  }

}
```

Comment: Please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I want to trigger a function when I select any value from a dropdown. Using that function, I want to assign values to next dropdown  based on the value selected from previous one.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `ngModel`

```
<ion-select ngModel (ngModelChange)='f()' name="xxx">
```

I'm not sure if the `ngModel` part is needed to get `ngModel` applied at all. You can try to remove it and see if it's still working.

Three also seems to be an `ionChange` event

```
<ion-select (ionChange)='f()' name="xxx">
```

http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/select/Select/

Comment: Thanks a lot. (ionChange) will do the job.

Comment: As I mentioned previously I need selected value for which I am using above mentioned code but it is not working fine. Can you provide some guidelines regarding this also

Comment: have you tried `(ionChange)="f($event)"` with `f(event) { console.log(event);}`?

Answer (score 3):

You can use ionSelect on ion-option this will fire each time the item is selected.

[Ionic docs ion-option](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/option/Option/)

```
<ion-select>
    <ion-option (ionSelect)="optionSelected($event)" *ngFor="let item of items$ | async" [value]="item.id">{{item.name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Comment: I might be missing something, but for my purposes, using ionSelect at the ion-option instead of calling ionChange at ion-select allows me to send a value from the ngFor iterator. That did the trick. Thanks @chriscooley